# SEO friendly redirect in .htaccess blocks subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have this code in my .htaccess to make my URLs SEO friendly and pretty:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now I notice that a subfolder (gallery.mysite.com ) set by my webhotel does no longer work. It gets redirected to index.php and seems to try to load an empty var (page).

Is there a way to force the subdomain not getting redirected?

I have tried this but it doesn't quite get there...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gallery\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!sub1/).*)$ sub1/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^gallery\. [NC]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^gallery\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly! :)